# Type of input stream passed to jersey form data parameter

Tags: java, jersey, inputstream, jersey-2.0

What is the type of input stream passed to `@FormDataParam` when uploading an image?

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("text/html")
public void uploadImage(@FormDataParam("image") InputStream inputStream, 
                        @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                        @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Input streams do not have types. They are just streams of byte data. What that data is - depends on what was sent via form data part.

Comment: I meant types like FileInputStream or ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: probably neither if that's a "true" REST call. You shouldn't actually be concerned with that. Why would you be?

Comment: what does the type depend on? I need it while processing the input stream

Comment: no you don't. It doesn't matter where bytestream comes from specifically. What matters is only the content, and you can only get it by consuming a stream or demanding the encoding and format from the caller.

Comment: lets say I want to call inputstream.available() , this will depend of type of input stream we get !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168727/discussion-between-mysticforce-and-m-prokhorov).

Comment: Even though "available()" depends on a type of stream, it doesn't mean that you absolutely _need_ to know what type of stream it is. Unless you actually explain why it matters to you, ofc.

Comment: Why do you need to know? An InputStream is just a stream of bytes. Since jersey might change over in future versions, you probably don't want to depend on the stream implementation Jersey provides you with since it might change. If you tell us why you need to know we might be able to help you find an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `InputStream` you can use `byte[]` as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response attachupload(
        @FormDataParam("file") byte[] is,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @FormDataParam("fileName") String flename) {

    attachService.saveAttachment(flename,is);
}
```

Comment: do I need to change anything in the form for this transformation?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.